# geometric vs arithmetic sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am wondering how to quickly find if a sequence is arithmetic or geometric sequence.

for example. $a_n =exp(n)$ is geometric sequence because $$\frac{e^{n+1}}{e^n}=e=\frac{e^{n+2}}{e^{n+1}}$$

but I have 2 questions here:

1) does the proof above make sure that $a_n$ is not arithmetic? a sequence cannot be arithmetic and geometric at the same time, right?

2) what about more complex expressions? like $b_n=ln(n)$? how do I quickly see if it is arithmetic or geometric sequence?

Comment: 1. Yes - for $a_n=aq^n$ we have $a_{n+1}-a_n = aq^n(q-1)$, which is not constant, unless $q=0$ or $q=1$.
2. In general, sequences are neither arithmetic nor geometric. Your sequence $b_n=\log n$ is an example.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś thank you, didnot know that sequences are in general none of them. nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a constant sequence can be arithmetic and geometric at the same time:
$$\frac{a+2d}{a+d}=\frac{a+d}a$$
$$a^2+2ad+d^2=a^2+2ad$$
so $d=0$.

To check if a sequence is arithmetic, compute $a_{n+1}-a_n$. If the result depends on $n$, it is not arithmetic. For geometric ones, it's the same, but this time compute $a_{n+1}/a_n$.